I can't call the callback page after making a successful payment on paystack
'I made a successful payment but can't call the callback page? Or is there something wrong that I don't know about?
setting paystack
I want after making payment to go to verify.php page but it's not possible, or is it because I'm using localhost
Help me'
pay.php
<?php
  require_once 'session.php';
  require_once '../constants.php';
  if (!isset($_SESSION['amount'], $_SESSION['email'])) {
    @session_destroy();
    header("Location: ../");
    exit;
  }

  

  $pay = curl_init();
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
  $amount = $_SESSION['amount'] . "00";
  // die($amount);
  curl_setopt_array($pay, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize" ,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",

    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
      'amount' => $amount,
      'email' => $email,
    ]),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
      "authorization: Bearer $paystack", 
      "content-type: application/json",
      "cache-control: no-cache"
    ],
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($pay);
  $err = curl_error($pay);
  if ($err) {
    header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment&access=0");
    exit();
  }
  $tranx = json_decode($response);
  if (!$tranx->status or empty($tranx->status)) {
    // đã xảy ra lỗi từ API
    header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment&access=1");
    exit();
  }

  header('Location: ' . $tranx->data->authorization_url);
  

verify.php
i want to go to this page affter payment but it doesn't do that
<?php
require_once 'session.php';
require_once '../conn.php';
require_once '../constants.php';



if (isset($_GET['reference'])) {
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
  $reference = $_GET['reference'];
  $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

  $pay = curl_init();
  $paid = $_SESSION['original'];
  $schedule_id = $_SESSION['schedule'];
  $number = $_SESSION['no'];
  $class = $_SESSION['class'];
  $price = 0;

  $amount = $_SESSION['amount'] . "00";
  curl_setopt_array($pay, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/" . rawurlencode($reference),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
      "accept: application/json",
      "authorization: Bearer $paystack",
      "cache-control: no-cache"
    ],
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($pay);
  
  $err = curl_error($pay);
  if ($err) {
    // đã xảy ra lỗi khi liên hệ với API Paystack
    header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment");
    exit();
  }

  if ($response) {

    $result = json_decode($response, true);

    // if ($resul->data->status == 'success'){
    if (array_key_exists('data', $result) 
      && array_key_exists('status', $result['data']) 
      && ($result['data']['status'] === 'success') 
      && ($result['data']['requested_amount'] === intval($amount))) {
      //xác nhận quyền truy cập vào trang thanh toán thành công
      $paid = substr($paid, 0, -2);
      $reference = strtoupper($reference);
      $ins = $conn->query("INSERT INTO payment (passenger_id, schedule_id, amount, ref, date) VALUES ('$user_id','$schedule_id', '$paid', '$reference', '$date')");
      $code = genCode($schedule_id, $user_id, $class);
      $seat = genSeat($schedule_id, $class, $number);
      $payment_id = $conn->insert_id;
      if ($payment_id > 0) {

        $conn->query("INSERT INTO booked (payment_id, schedule_id, user_id, code, class, no, date, seat) VALUES ('$payment_id','$schedule_id', '$user_id', '$code', '$class', '$number', '$date' , '$seat')");
        unset($_SESSION['discount']);
        unset($_SESSION['amount']);
        unset($_SESSION['original']);
        unset($_SESSION['schedule']);
        unset($_SESSION['no']);
        unset($_SESSION['class']);
        $_SESSION['pay_success'] = 'true';
        $_SESSION['has_paid'] = 'true';
        header("Location: individual.php?page=paid&now=true");
        exit();
      }
    }
     else {
      header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment");
      exit();
    }
    header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment");
    exit();
  }
  header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment");
  exit();
}
header("Location: individual.php?page=pay&error=payment");
exit();


The callback URL is a URL within your system, that the user will get redirected back to. From your screenshot, it appears that you input the URL of one of the payment provider's API endpoints.

That's right, I want to call back to the address in my system. Is that possible? Also I have this message appear
{
"status": false,
"message": "No Authorization Header was found",
"meta": {
"nextStep": "Ensure that the authorization header follows the format: "Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY". Ex. 'Authorization: Bearer sk_123456789'"
},
"type": "validation_error",
"code": "authorization_key"
}

It is supposed to be a URL in your system. As for the Authorization header - capitalization of header names should not matter, but perhaps this API is of a different opinion. If that's not it, then you'll have to do a bit more debugging.

You need to set the callback_url when initializing the transaction to the URL of the page you want to redirect to.
...

$callbackUrl = "https://your-website.com/verify.php"; // Replace with your actual callback URL

curl_setopt_array($pay, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    'amount' => $amount,
    'email' => $email,
    'callback_url' => $callbackUrl, // Add this line
  ]),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "authorization: Bearer $paystack", 
    "content-type: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ],
));

...

